# Django Model don't save if conditions are met

Tags: django, django-models

Im am trying to save instance of `MyModel` only if conditions are met, in my case I want to save just if child objects of my Model fields are equal, example:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.field1.obj == self.field2.obj:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried code above and it stills saving when `obj` in fields are not the same.

1. Why it is still saving when save method from super is not being called?
2. Is it possible to set an else statement on my example to tell explicitly **DON'T SAVE**?

Comment: it should not save. Comparing two objects equal is also non trivial in python for what you would like to achieve. For what its worth you can do else: raise Exception and see if that gets called

Comment: Saving how? In the admin? There's unfortunately a lot of ways to bypass Django's `model.save()` method, including several admin actions. Condiser also [`QuerySet.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments, in my test I was using

```
modelInstance = MyModelFactory.create(field1=field1, field2=field2)
assertNotIsInstance(modelInstance, MyModel)
```

Even when it is not saving to database somehow it always return an unsaved instance.

When I updated my test to check.

```
assertEqual(0, MyModel.objects.count())
```

It worked.

Sorry for this noob question.

Comment: Where is assertNotIsInstance coming from??